# Can I/O latency cause a simple UPDATE to take seconds in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, vps, disk-io

My MySQL application is experiencing **slow performance** when running some `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` queries. In this question, I will only discuss one particular `UPDATE`, because it's enough to demonstrate the problem:

```
UPDATE projects SET ring = 5 WHERE id = 1
```

This `UPDATE` is usually fast enough, around 0.2ms, but every now and then (enough to be a problem) **it takes several seconds**. Here's an excerpt from the log (look at the 4th line):

```
 ~ (0.000282) UPDATE `projects` SET `ring` = 5 WHERE `id` = 1
 ~ (0.000214) UPDATE `projects` SET `ring` = 6 WHERE `id` = 1
 ~ (0.000238) UPDATE `projects` SET `ring` = 7 WHERE `id` = 1
 ~ (3.986502) UPDATE `projects` SET `ring` = 8 WHERE `id` = 1
 ~ (0.000186) UPDATE `projects` SET `ring` = 9 WHERE `id` = 1
 ~ (0.000217) UPDATE `projects` SET `ring` = 0 WHERE `id` = 1
 ~ (0.000162) UPDATE `projects` SET `ring` = 1 WHERE `id` = 1
```

`projects` is an InnoDB table with 6 columns of types `INT` and `VARCHAR`, 17 rows and an index on `id`. It happens with other tables too, but here I'm focusing on this one. When trying to solve the problem, I ensured that the queries were all sequential, so this is **not a lock issue**. The `UPDATE` above is executed in the context of a transaction. Other **information on the server**:

- VPS with 4GB RAM (was 1GB), 12GB free disk space
- CentoOS 5.8 (was 5.7)
- MySQL 5.5.10 (was 5.0.x)

The "was" bit above means it didn't work before or after the upgrade.

**What I've tried so far, to no avail**:

- Setting `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` to 0, 1 or 2
- Setting `innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog` on or off
- Setting `timed_mutexes` on or off
- Changing `innodb_flush_method` from the default to `O_DSYNC` or `O_DIRECT`
- Increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` from the default to 600M and then to 3000M
- Increasing `innodb_log_file_size` from the default to 128M
- Compiling MySQL from source
- Running `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, which informs me that the state is "updating"
- Running `SHOW PROFILE ALL`, which says that almost all the time was spent on "updating", and that, within that step, not so much time was spent on CPU cycles and there were many voluntary context switches (like 30)
- Monitoring `SHOW STATUS` for changes in `Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty`. There may be some relation between dirty pages being flushed and the slow queries, but the correlation isn't clear.

Then I decided to check the system's I/O latency with `ioping`. This is my first VPS, so **I was surprised to see this result**:

```
4096 bytes from . (vzfs /dev/vzfs): request=1 time=249.2 ms
4096 bytes from . (vzfs /dev/vzfs): request=2 time=12.3 ms
4096 bytes from . (vzfs /dev/vzfs): request=3 time=110.5 ms
4096 bytes from . (vzfs /dev/vzfs): request=4 time=232.8 ms
4096 bytes from . (vzfs /dev/vzfs): request=5 time=294.4 ms
4096 bytes from . (vzfs /dev/vzfs): request=6 time=704.7 ms
4096 bytes from . (vzfs /dev/vzfs): request=7 time=1115.0 ms
4096 bytes from . (vzfs /dev/vzfs): request=8 time=209.7 ms
4096 bytes from . (vzfs /dev/vzfs): request=9 time=64.2 ms
4096 bytes from . (vzfs /dev/vzfs): request=10 time=396.2 ms
```

Pretty erratic, I would say.

**Having said all of that, I ask:**

1. **Can the I/O latency be occasionally killing MySQL performance?** I always thought that, when you ran an `UPDATE`, the thread taking care of that connection wasn't going to flush data to disk or wait for such a flush; it would return immediately and the flushing would be done by another thread at another time.
2. If it can't be disk I/O, **is there anything else I can possibly try, short of renting a dedicated server?**

Comment: Is it the COMMIT that takes 5 seconds, or the actual UPDATE?

Comment: `UPDATE` should normally - just as you're saying - not flush to disk, only `COMMIT` would flush the log while running in your thread (and innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0 should turn even that off) Your I/O latency is definitely out of control(!), but unless the load is high enough to not allow caching of the 17 row table for read, I can't see how it would be the cause of this exact problem.

Comment: Exactly: even this out-of-control latency shouldn't cause such a delay! The load on my VPS is only me using it. Along with this UPDATE, some SELECTs are performed on a table with more than 1 million rows, and those are always fast.

Comment: It's possible that your final suggestion (re: dedicated server) hit the nail on the head. Short of using a dedicated server, are you able to move your VPS to a different physical host?

Comment: I don't know if my provider, myhosting.com, would move my VPS around their servers. I'm trying to avoid the dedicated server option because they're much more expensive (this is for a small, personal project). I could switch to another provider, but -- and this is what *really* bothers me -- I haven't been able to determine the cause of the problem, so I don't know if moving to another provider would fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm replying to my own question with additional data that I collected based on your answers.

I used two notebooks connected by means of a wireless network. On notebook A, I
mounted a directory of notebook B using `sshfs`. Then on notebook A I started up
MySQL specifying that mounted directory as its data directory. This should
provide MySQL with a very slow I/O device. MySQL was started with
`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0`.

I defined 3 sets of queries, each set consisting of an update and a select query
repeated 10,000 times, without explicit transactions. The experiments were:

- US1SID: update and select on a specific row of the same table. The same row
  was used in all iterations.
- US1MID: update and select on a specific row of the same table. The row was a
  different one in each iteration.
- US2MID: update and select on rows of different tables. In this case, the table
  being read by the select didn't change at all during the experiment.

Each set was run twice using a shell script (hence timings are slower than those in my original question), one under normal conditions and the other after executing the following command:

```
tc qdisc replace dev wlan0 root handle 1:0 netem delay 200ms
```

The command above adds a mean delay of 200ms when transmitting packets through wlan0.

First, here's the mean time of the top 99% fastest updates and selects, and the
bottom 1% updates and selects.

```
          |        Delay: 0ms        |       Delay: 200ms       |
          | US1SID | US1MID | US2MID | US1SID | US1MID | US2MID |
| top99%u | 0.0064 | 0.0064 | 0.0064 | 0.0063 | 0.0063 | 0.0063 |
| top99%s | 0.0062 | 0.0063 | 0.0063 | 0.0062 | 0.0062 | 0.0062 |
| bot01%u | 1.1834 | 1.2239 | 0.9561 | 1.9461 | 1.7492 | 1.9731 |
| bot01%s | 0.4600 | 0.5391 | 0.3417 | 1.4424 | 1.1557 | 1.6426 |
```

As is clear, even with really, really poor I/O performance, MySQL manages to
execute most queries really fast. But what concerns me the most is the worst
cases, so here's another table, showing the 10 slowest queries. A "u" means it
was an update, an "s" a select.

```
|          Delay: 0ms         |          Delay: 200ms          |
| US1SID  | US1MID  | US2MID  | US1SID   | US1MID   | US2MID   |
| 5.443 u | 5.946 u | 5.315 u | 11.500 u | 10.860 u | 11.424 s |
| 5.581 u | 5.954 s | 5.466 u | 11.649 s | 10.995 u | 11.496 s |
| 5.863 s | 6.291 u | 5.658 u | 12.551 s | 11.020 u | 12.221 s |
| 6.192 u | 6.513 u | 5.685 u | 12.893 s | 11.370 s | 12.599 u |
| 6.560 u | 6.521 u | 5.736 u | 13.526 u | 11.387 u | 12.803 u |
| 6.562 u | 6.555 u | 5.743 u | 13.997 s | 11.497 u | 12.920 u |
| 6.872 u | 6.575 u | 5.869 u | 14.662 u | 12.825 u | 13.625 u |
| 6.887 u | 7.908 u | 5.996 u | 19.953 u | 12.860 u | 13.828 s |
| 6.937 u | 8.100 u | 6.330 u | 20.623 u | 14.015 u | 16.292 u |
| 8.665 u | 8.298 u | 6.893 u | 27.102 u | 22.042 s | 17.131 u |
```

Conclusions:

1. Poor I/O performance can indeed slow MySQL to a crawl. It's not clear *why*
   or *when* exactly, but it does happen.
2. The slowing down applies to both selects and updates, with updates suffering
   more.
3. For some reason, even selects on a table that wasn't involved in any changes,
   and which had recently been populated, were also slowed down, as is clear
   from US2MID above.
4. As for the test cases proposed by mentatkgs, it seems that updating different
   rows instead of the same ones does help a little, but doesn't solve the
   problem.

I guess I will either adapt my software to tolerate such delays or try to move
to another provider. Renting a dedicated server is too expensive for this
project.

Thank you all for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

As you are hosting your VPS in the cloud, you might be running into issues that are completely out of your control.

VPSs are subject to the whims of the host servers that run them. For example, CPU cycle priority at the Rackspace Cloud is weighted based on the size of the VPS. The bigger your VPS, the better likelihood that your app will perform smoothly. If there is a bigger VPS on the host you're using, it's *possible* that there is weighted bursting to blame. It's pretty hard to say.

Have you tried running this locally on your own machine? If it runs perfectly on your own system, and you need guaranteed performance, then your best bet will be to move to a dedicated server.

Comment: On other machines it runs fine. Performance is important for my application, but since renting a dedicated server would be much more expensive, at least for the time being I will try to adapt the software to these delays. In a few minutes I'll post some other results I obtained that helped clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have a VPS-related IO problem. It's not MySQL's fault.

Are you by any chance using Elastic Block Store with Amazon, or possibly RDS? Both of those use remote storage, and an IP protocol layer to talk to the storage; they can have nasty lag at times.

Comment: I'm using Myhosting.com. I never thought this was, e.g., a bug in MySQL. I just don't quite understand its behavior. (Basically, if a table is in memory, why does MySQL block when updating it?)

Comment: A MySQL table is never guaranteed 'in memory', although MySQL will work hard to keep indices in memory. If you need a true in-memory db, then depending on your requirements, you could check out sqlite (not good for concurrency, but fast and easy for many things), a NoSQL solution like redis, or some of the more modern column store databases which offer a bit more control here.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1) Yes.

To check it write 2 apps:

Test case 1: will do this every minuto for a few hours

```
UPDATE `projects` SET `ring` = 5 WHERE `id` = 1
UPDATE `projects` SET `ring` = 6 WHERE `id` = 1
```

Test case 2: will do this every minute for a few hours

```
UPDATE `projects` SET `ring` = 7 WHERE `id` = 1
UPDATE `projects` SET `ring` = 8 WHERE `id` = 2
```

Test case 1 should have a delay, while test case 2 should not.

Question 2) Use a noSQL database.

Comment: In a few minutes I'm going to post a reply answering my question. I ran some experiments the results of which partly support your arguments. Using NoSQL is out of the question though :P